# My data ouput on pgAdmin 4 only displays column names and no rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

[visual representation showing myissue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsXrW.png)When I execute a query to view a table on pgAdmin 4, the output only shows the column headers and a locked key, it doesn't display the rows of the tables. I tried copying the table but, the copy icon is not highlighted, so i cannot copy te table.
Please what do i do to be able to view the table completely

Query;
SELECT * FROM trading.members

Comment: Can you provide us your query? The most common reason is using "select from table" construction without using any columns after "select". But better to see your example to determine the issue

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question (by clicking on the [edit] link below it) and add the complete query you are using as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) (no screenshots please. [edit] your question - do **not** put code or additional information in comments). But most probably your WHERE clause simply filters out all rows. Or your table is empty.

Answer (score 3):

This issue happened to me as well. PgAdmin 4.30 was saying "Rows affected xxx", but no results in the grid. I could even download the results as a csv, so I knew the query and connection etc was fine. Tried resetting the layout, but no dice.

Long story short - it turned out to be a Chrome plugin I have going that changes pages to dark mode. It wasn't just making the results grid hard to see, it was completely crashing the table. The entire `<div>` was just empty - and no console error was present either. The rest of the site was seemingly unchanged. The plugin is called "Dark Reader", for reference.

Disabling the plugin and re-running the query fixed my issue.

Comment: Turns out I had the same issue, though, I've been using Dark Reader for years without issue. This question is a year old, did this issue just start happening for you? Disabling Dark Ready certainly fixes the issue,  but unfortunate to have this problem out of the blue.

Comment: I've also been using it for at least a couple of years, and have also been using this version of PgAdmin for a couple of years, without issue. My guess is that there was an update to the plugin, hopefully they get it patched soon because light mode disagrees with my eyes.